# svn - how to export only UNversioned items

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I build my software which creates bunch of unversioned objects which I want to keep (to compare with next build).

How do I only export UNversioned items from a versioned directory?

Comment: well usually you just push it up.. then build the next set and then do a SVN compare which will compare local copy to SVN repo. Or just create a branch and compare the two

Comment: @3kings I don't want to check in the artifacts. Neither does my sw lead.

Comment: most likely make a branch then? can you do that ?

Comment: @3kings no because I would still have to check it into the repo.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting? You want to keep versions of these "artifacts" to compare versions, but you don't want to put them in version control (which is what this is used for). I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @mrunion my version control is on a company server; they don't want artifacts checked in.

Comment: @mrunion "How do I only export UNversioned items from a versioned directory?" What isn't clear?

Comment: Write a script to get results from an "svn status", read the results, parse what's not versioned? Doesn't SVN show you what's not versioned in it's output status? What OS are you running (I ask because you could do this real easy from Unix command(s)). And by "export" do you mean "remove from the directory"?